# Fixed width for box using tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

How to set fixed width (50pt or any other fixed value) for box using `tcolorbox`. Please find MWE file below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{rhbox}{colback=red,colframe=red,
boxsep=1pt,boxrule=1pt,top=3pt,bottom=3pt,left=3pt,right=3pt, %left skip=38.5pt,
arc=5pt,width=50pt}

\begin{document}

\rhbox{\thepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Drop `left=3pt,right=3pt,`. Otherwise you will give `tcolorbox` conflicting information.

Comment: Yes, I got it.Thank you